# How to use Not Equals in Postgresql Joins

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing this:

```
 select * from schema2."Student" a INNER JOIN    
schema1."StudentMapping" b on ( a."StudentID" = b."StudentID") 
where a."IsRemoved" = false AND b."IsRemoved" = false
```

to get only those records from `Student` table that are present in `StudentMapping` table, here `IsRemoved` column I'm using for soft deletion(i.e, whenever any record is to be deleted from any of those tables then only I'm setting it to `true`, so for `IsRemoved = false` records are present in the tables) and the query is working fine. Now what I wanted is to get all those records from `Student` table that are not present in `StudentMapping` table so I tried this:

```
select * from schema2."Student" a INNER JOIN      
schema1."StudentMapping" b on ( a."StudentId" != b."StudentId") 
where a."IsRemoved" = false AND
b."IsRemoved" = false
```

but this is giving lot of records, more than I expected, what is wrong with this query or is there another way in `Postgresql` to get all matching recording from one table that are not present in another table.

Comment: Aside: it is extremely rare that you actually need to do `= false` or `= true` in any strongly typed language. It always looks more professional to simply use the boolean value directly: `!a."IsRemoved" AND !b."IsRemoved"`. Also, consider doing away with mixed case and quoting when you create the table: `is_removed` instead of `"IsRemoved"`. This casing and quote marks will only ever be a hassle to everyone. (Unlike [some databases](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html), PG has *plenty* of room for longer, clearer names.)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then in the `where` clause, specify to only show recods where the join resulted in a NULL:

```
select * from schema1."Student" a LEFT OUTER JOIN    
schema1."StudentMapping" b on ( a."StudentID" = b."StudentID") 
where a."IsRemoved" = false
and b.StudentID IS NULL
```

Comment: its giving empty result, I edited the question schemas for 2 tables are different

Comment: its giving results but one problem is there, see, in Student table 982 rows are there for which "IsRemoved" = false and in my first query on getting records from Student table that are present in StudentMapping table I am getting result as 4 rows that is also right, so on running ur query for not matching results I am supposed to get 982 - 4 = 978 records, but I'm getting 927 rows on running your query and which i think is not right

Comment: @Aamir that can happen, if your `IsRemoved` flag is not synchronized. In this case, you should move the tests for `IsRemoved` into the `ON` clause, like `ON a."StudentID" = b."StudentID" AND NOT b."IsRemoved"` (the `WHERE` clause still needs the `NOT a."IsRemoved"` test).

Comment: like this I tried still getting incorrect results `select * from base."Employee" a  LEFT OUTER JOIN  hr."LeaveProfileConfigEmpMapping" b on ( a."EmployeeId" = b."EmployeeId" AND ( a."IsRemoved" = false AND b."IsRemoved" = false )) where 
b."EmployeeId" IS NULL`, correct the query plz if its wrong